# Python return function not giving value

Tags: python

In python code, I've written:

```
x = 1
y = 2
def add_nums(first, second):
  sum = first + second
  return sum
```

And when I do:

```
add_nums(x, y)
```

It returns nothing what is wrong with the code?

Comment: It **does** return something, what do you *do with it*? Assign it? Print it?

Comment: When you execute code as a script, values are not printed like they are when you use Python interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns its local `sum` variable. Perhaps you meant to print it

```
print(add_nums(x, y))
```